# How to pass an array in as dropdown menu items?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, drop-down-menu, ruby-on-rails-4, simple-form

How can I convert this haml code to display a dropdown of the menu items instead of a list?

Existing code within our rails 4.0 app:

app/views/application/_archive.html.haml

```
.sidebar-header=I18n.t('blog.archive')
-archive_dates.each do |date|
    .archive-link=archive_link(date, '%B %Y')
```

app/models/post.rb

```
def self.archive_dates(audience)
    archive_dates = Array.new
    published.send(audience).each do |post|
      archive_dates << post.publish_date.to_date if archive_dates.count == 0 || post.publish_date.month != archive_dates.last.month || post.publish_date.year != archive_dates.last.year
    end
    archive_dates
end
```

app/helpers/application_helper.rb:

```
def archive_link(archive_date, format)
    archive_date = archive_date.to_date
    link_to I18n.l(archive_date, format: format), posts_path(month: archive_date.month, year: archive_date.year)
  end
```

This is the output HTML.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/bFaxf.png

Users are able to select a month and display all posts made during that month.  I am looking for the same format and behaviour, but must use a dropdown menu instead.

Comment: to pass a array in drop down you can use
= select_tag "name", options_from_collection_for_select(@name, "id", "desc")
or 
= select_tag "name", options_for_select(@name)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would show a drop down menu with labels as the formatted link tags and values as the actual link.

```
= select_tag "name_of_tag" , options_for_select( archive_dates.map{ |date| 
                              [archive_link(date, '%B %Y').html_safe, #label
                              posts_path(month: date.month, year: date.year),  #value
                              :class => "archive_date" ] # class of each option
                            }), onchange: "window.location = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;"
```

Need to use `html_safe` for each label to make it appear as raw html.

Added the `onchange` html option to take the user to the selected option whenever it is selected.

Comment: Thanks tihom, im still having some difficulty getting the onchange option to work.  Where should this be added?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the select tag in your view for e.g.

```
= select_tag 'user_id', options_for_select(@users.collect{ |u| [u.name, u.id] })
# change the value of options_for_select as per your requirement
```

Comment: Thanks, I've got it working to some extent using 

`= select_tag "Archive link", options_for_select(archive_dates)`

But this only displays dates posts were made.  How can I include the  archive_link to keep the orginal formatting and display posts grouped together by month?

Comment: How you want to display it? can you please provide the format.